# Are infinite Ramsey numbers completely known?

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that Erdős did some work in infinitary combinatorics in the hope that it would be easier than finite combinatorics, since infinite is the limit of finite. This is true especially in Ramsey theory. For simplicity let us focus on edge coloring. The notation $\lambda\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_\tau$ means for any coloring on a complete graph with $\lambda$ many vertices, using $\tau$ many colors, there is a homogeneous (monochromatic) set of cardinality $\kappa$; any of the three cardinalities might be infinite. Ramsey himself proved the first interesting infinite case: $\aleph_0\rightarrow(\aleph_0)^2_k$ for any finite $k$ (he used it to prove some theorem in logic); this implies the finite version.

Then there is the Erdős-Rado Theorem $(2^\kappa)^+\rightarrow(\kappa^+)^2_\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, and this is optimal; $\kappa^+$ means the next infinity after $\kappa$. Although I didn't find it in standard textbooks, my understanding is that the proof also shows $\kappa^+\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_\tau$ if either (a) $\kappa$ is a strong limit singular cardinal and $\tau<\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$, or (b) $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal and $\tau<\kappa$. Case (a) is clearly optimal, and case (b) can be improved to $\kappa\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_\tau$ iff $\kappa$ is a weakly compact cardinal (this is basically one of the equivalent definitions of being weakly compact), and weakly compact cardinals, though independent, are fairly well understood.

None of the above proofs is super difficult, and they all generalize to hypergraphs. Compare this to the situation in finite combinatorics where the least value of $n$ satisfying $n\rightarrow(k)^2_2$ is wide open for $k=5$, and completely out of reach for $k=6$. However, the above doesn't answer the problem of finding the least $\lambda$ satisfying $\lambda\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_\tau$ in the following cases:

1. $\kappa$ weakly inaccessible but not strong limit, $\tau<\kappa$;
2. $\kappa$ singular cardinal but not strong limit;
3. $\kappa$ strong limit singular cardinal, $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)\leq\tau<\kappa$.

Are these Ramsey numbers also known? In the first two cases $\lambda$ is at least $\sup_{\eta<\kappa}2^\eta$, besides which I don't know any more. For the third case I think I have an example showing $\kappa^+\not\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$: write $\kappa=\lim_{i<\text{cf}(\kappa)}\kappa_i$, and for each $\alpha<\kappa^+$ fix a surjection $f_\alpha:\kappa\rightarrow\alpha$; for $\alpha<\beta<\kappa^+$, find an $\xi<\kappa$ such that $f_\beta(\xi)=\alpha$, say $\xi\in[\kappa_i,\kappa_{i+1})$, and give the edge $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ color $i$. If there were a homogeneous set $H$ of size $\kappa$ and color $i$, then choosing the $\kappa_{i+2}$-th point in $H$ should produce a contradiction. Thus in the third case $\lambda\geq\kappa^{++}$, and unless SCH fails at $\kappa$, we have $\kappa^{++}=(2^\kappa)^+$ so indeed $\lambda=\kappa^{++}$.

Edit: Actually $2^\kappa\not\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$, so in the third case $\lambda$ is just $(2^\kappa)^+$. Notations as above, for different $A,B\subseteq\kappa$, let $i<\text{cf}(\kappa)$ be the least such that $A\cap\kappa_i\neq B\cap\kappa_i$. Since $\kappa$ is strong limit there cannot be a homogeneous set of size $\kappa$.

For the first two cases, if the continuum function $\eta\mapsto 2^\eta$ is eventually constant below $\kappa$, then $2^\kappa$ equals that value by elementary cardinal arithmetic, and since $2^\eta\not\rightarrow(\eta^+)^2_2$ we have $2^\kappa\not\rightarrow(\kappa)^2_2$, so again $(2^\kappa)^+$ is best possible. There still remains the case when the continuum function is not eventually constant.